# How to Dynamically create fields and automatically add the values of the filled fields

Tags: javascript, addition, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to add several forms dynamically and when generated automatically add the quantity filled inside the forms for each "player".
I've successfully be able to create the inputs but I don't know how to code the "adding" part.

Maybe my code can explain better my practice project
(It's for a personal practice project and to be used only with friends.)
My Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addFields(){
            var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i=0;i<number;i++){
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Jugador " + (i+1)));
    
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                input.name = "Jugador" + i;
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    input.value = "Nombre del Jugador " +(1+ i);
                container.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Puntuación de las rondas"));
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "Number";
                input.name = "Ronda 1" + i;
    input.value = "1";
                container.appendChild(input);
    var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "Number";
                input.name = "Ronda 2" + i;
    input.value = "2";
                container.appendChild(input);
    var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "Number";
                input.name = "Ronda 3" + i;
    input.value = "3";
                container.appendChild(input);
    var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "Number";
                input.name = "Ronda 4" + i;
    input.value = "4";
                container.appendChild(input);
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Total"));
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        }
    </script>
<style>
.myButton {
 background-color:#44c767;
 -moz-border-radius:28px;
 -webkit-border-radius:28px;
 border-radius:28px;
 border:1px solid #18ab29;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:14px;
 padding:12px 21px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
.myButton:hover {
 background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
.myButton:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
</style>

<title>Galle -GO- Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
<b>Número de jugadores:</b>
  <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="2"><br /><br />
    <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()" class="myButton">Generar Partida</a>
    <div id="container"/><br />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two typo error.

1. The one cause Issue is there is an extra `s` (typo) before last 
   `container.appendChild` .
2. Second you have not closed `div` like `<\div>`. But I guess this doesn't cause the issue. Just an observation.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addFields(){
            var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i=0;i<number;i++){
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Jugador " + (i+1)));
    
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                input.name = "Jugador" + i;
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    input.value = "Nombre del Jugador " +(1+ i);
                container.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Puntuación de las rondas"));
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "Number";
                input.name = "Ronda 1" + i;
    input.value = "1";
                container.appendChild(input);
    var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "Number";
                input.name = "Ronda 2" + i;
    input.value = "2";
                container.appendChild(input);
    var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "Number";
                input.name = "Ronda 3" + i;
    input.value = "3";
                container.appendChild(input);
    var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "Number";
                input.name = "Ronda 4" + i;
    input.value = "4";
                container.appendChild(input);
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Total"));
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        }
    </script>
<style>
.myButton {
 background-color:#44c767;
 -moz-border-radius:28px;
 -webkit-border-radius:28px;
 border-radius:28px;
 border:1px solid #18ab29;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:14px;
 padding:12px 21px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
.myButton:hover {
 background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
.myButton:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
</style>

<title>Galle -GO- Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
<b>Número de jugadores:</b>
  <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="2"><br /><br />
    <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()" class="myButton">Generar Partida</a>
    <div id="container"></div><br />

</body>
</html>
```